# Protect API using IdentityServer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

I've started using IdentityServer4, using the ASP.NET Identity and Entity Framework sample.

There is an MVC application, which uses IdentityServer to get an access token, using 'client credentials and hybrid' grant types, and uses this access token to call APIs.

The solution look like this:

- Identity Server Project
- MVC Project
- API Project

I'm about to add a new private API, but I'd like to restrict this so that only the MVC application can call it, and only on the server side.

My original idea was to add a new API scope for this private API and only give that scope to the MVC application. The problem with this is that I understand that the access token is freely accessible from the MVC application to the user, and therefore they could get access to the token and therefore call the private API with their own parameters.

What would be the suggested manor to secure an API, such that an access token could be obtained by an attacker and provide access to the API?

Would I need to create a new 'client credentials' based client which is used by the MVC application? It'd seem a bit odd to have the MVC project using two separate clients for the same API?

For information, the AddAuthentication in the MVC app looks like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
```

I believe is should be similar, if not the same as the IdentityServer samples.

Comment: *“the access token is freely accessible from the MVC application to the user”* – How do you authenticate users in your MVC application? Where is the token stored, where is it being transmitted? Is this a server-side MVC app, or a client-side SPA? When accessing your new private API, do you need to act on behalf of the user?

Comment: Hey, good questions. Users are authenticated using the login page on the IdentityServer, so I'm guessing that at some stage, the access token will in the redirect which is picked up by the MVC application. I'm not sure where it's stored (apologies, still learning about IdentityServer), but I'm guessing it's somewhere accessible by the user? I can't find any documentation to suggest it can be treated as secure. It's a server side MVC app and no, this private API will be called without the context of a user.

Comment: If you want to separate permission, and don't allow user to connect to our 'api', you need to different scope for `mvc` and `api`. For `mvc` scope you can use password grant type. For `api` scope - client_credentials grand type. And than user has permission only to `mvc`, and `mvc` has permission to `api`.

Comment: In your MVC’s `Startup` what does your `AddAuthentication()` call look like? What schemes do you use there? That should give us an idea how you integrate IdSrv into your app (which will tell us where the token is exposed). – If you don’t need the user context, you can also just make your MVC app have an internal client id/secret for separate access to your API. So you wouldn’t need the user’s token at all.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the help. I've updated the question, I use "Cookies", and "oidc". The private API doesn't need the user context, but the other APIs will. Would this mean that the API project would need to be defined as two separate Api Resources? The other thing I'm looking at is just sharing the application db context between the API and MVC project and using it to get read/write access to the data that I need, rather than a private API for. Feels like it breaks the nice separation I currently have though.

Comment: Since you are using cookie authentication, the token isn’t actually exposed to the user. There is just a protected cookie that contains the identity of the user. So you could use the access token for your private API as well.

Comment: Ah, so the cookie links to the access token which is kept server side only. Do you know of any documentation that describes this? Is it also kept secret during the login redirect flow from MVC > IdentityServer Login > MVC Callback? If it is, how is it transferred between the IdentityServer and MVC app? Sorry for all the questions, and thanks a lot for the help. It's much appreciated.

Comment: Whether it’s visible to the end user when authenticating with the OIDC provider depends on the selected authentication flow. At this time it’s probably a good idea to spend some time reading the OpenID Connect and possibly OAuth 2 specifications.

Comment: Fair comment, so much to read and learn. :) Thanks for the pointers. If you want to summarize in an answer, I'm happy to give you a vote and a tick.